# Having userscript permanently change Javascript on page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have been trying this for the past 3 days using Tampermonkey and I haven't gotten anywhere (I am an extreme newbie). So far I have just tried saving these files locally and seeing if Node.js could save the changes I made but no luck.

I need to change

```
<a href="javascript:notFinished()" onmouseover="if(module_next.src == 'images/navbar/next.gif'){changeImages('module_next', 'images/navbar/next_o.gif'); tag('Go to next page'); return true;}" onmouseout="if(module_next.src == 'images/navbar/next.gif'){changeImages('module_next', 'images/navbar/next.gif'); return true;}" name="module_next_href" id="module_next_href">
```

into

```
<a href="javascript:changePage(1)" onmouseover="if(module_next.src == 'images/navbar/next.gif'){changeImages('module_next', 'images/navbar/next_o.gif'); tag('Go to next page'); return true;}" onmouseout="if(module_next.src == 'images/navbar/next.gif'){changeImages('module_next', 'images/navbar/next.gif'); return true;}" name="module_next_href" id="module_next_href">
```

It needs to permanently stay like this, to apply this I just replace it manually but figured a script would be best.

Comment: Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Does anyone have any clue on this?

Comment: I am still needing assistance with this

Comment: Any help is still appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a script like this would be what you're looking for. Customize as needed - it finds the HTML elements with the tag `a` that match the `href` contents specified, and changes them.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          E
// @namespace     e
// @version       1
// @include       *google.com*
// @grant         GM_log
// @require       https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js
// @run-at        document-end
// ==/UserScript==

// Find an element using jQuery
var element = $("a[href='javascript:notFinished()']");

// Replace the href attribute of this element, if it exists
if (element.length > 0)
{
    element.attr('href', 'javascript:changePage(1)');
}
```